# How to stop serial reading on keyboard input

Tags: python, arduino

So I'm trying to make a program that reads out the serial port of my Arduino. This all works fine but the problem is I can't stop it when I want. My arduino keeps sending data (which is ok) but my script only stops after 100 line readings (as I set). After these 100 readings, it saves the list to a csv file. How can I stop earlier e.g. after typing 'stop' or 'exit' in terminal AND still save my data? ctrl+c just stops my script without saving.

My code:

```
import serial
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import time

portPath = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1411"       
baud = 9600                     
timeout = 5     # Seconds
filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "_shieldv1_water_data.csv"
max_num_readings = 100

def create_serial_obj(portPath, baud_rate, tout):
return serial.Serial(portPath, baud_rate, timeout = tout)

def read_serial_data(serial):
serial.flushInput()     # buffer flush

serial_data = []
readings_left = True
timeout_reached = False

while readings_left and not timeout_reached:
    serial_line = serial.readline()
    if  serial_line == '':
        timeout_reached = True
    else:  
        serial_data.append(serial_line.decode('utf-8'))
        if len(serial_data) == max_num_readings:
            readings_left = False

return serial_data

def save_to_csv(data, filename):
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwrite = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = '\n')
    csvwrite.writerow(data)


serial_obj = create_serial_obj(portPath, baud, timeout)

print("Reading serial data...")
serial_data = read_serial_data(serial_obj)

print("Saving to csv...")
save_to_csv(serial_data, filename)

print("Saved.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the check_input() function below. Put it into your loop, and break from that if the return value is not None. The poll() checks the standard input's buffer for characters following a newline, and if there are, reads them.

```
import select,sys,time

def check_input():

    po= select.poll()   
    po.register(sys.stdin.fileno(), select.POLLIN)  
    events= po.poll(0) 
    if events:
        for fno,ev in events:     
            if fno == sys.stdin.fileno():  
                return(input())
    return None

# testing:
if __name__ == "__main__":
   while True:
        s=check_input()
        if s:
            print("From keyboard:",s)
            break
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks very much!